# I'd like to change photos when mouse is on the pager of Bxslider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Instead of clicking the circles in bxSlider's pager, I'd like to hover with the mouse instead. But I have no idea what to do. I saw source code and changed from `click` to `hover`, for example at this part like [this site](http://www.webantena.net/javascriptjquery/customize-plugin-bxslider-hover-slide/).

from

```
slider.pagerEl.on('click', 'a', clickPagerBind);
```

to

```
slider.pagerEl.on('hover', 'a', clickPagerBind);
```

However, it didn't work. Would you please give me some advice?

```
BxSlider v4.1.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the details are commented in source. If you use `bxslider.min.js` hosted by CDN (like this demo), **do not** use the corresponding `bxslider.css` file. CDN doesn't handle assets correctly (or maybe I don't). Instead, host CSS file and assets (i.e. `loader.gif`, `controls.png`) in your own server.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$(function() {

  // Instantiate bxSlider to a var bx
  var bx = $('.bxSlider').bxSlider({

    /* Do not use useCSS option. bxSlider
    | does not handle animation that it doesn't 
    | handle itself very well.
    */
    useCSS: false
  });

  // Delegate mouseenter/leave events to .bx-pager-link
  $('.bx-pager-link').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {

    // Prevent <a> from jumping default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    /* Get the data-slide-index attribute value
    | and store it in var goTo.    
    | Next, use the bxSlider method goToSlide() 
    | to  move slides to the designated position
    | determined by the value of var goTo
    */
    var goTo = $(this).data('slide-index');
    bx.goToSlide(goTo);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Use bxslider.css for styles */

/* This demo has minimal styling 
| because CDN doesn't handle 
| assets correctly and for
| emphasis of specific controls
*/

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.bx-pager-item {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.bx-pager-link {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  color: rgba(255255, 255, .5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>


<ul class='bxSlider'>
  <li>
    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png'>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png'>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png'>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png'>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could check your code worked. I learned a lot. Thank you so much.